Inconsistent IPC Buffer Serialization Between Python and JavaScript
I'm experiencing an issue with IPC buffer serialization in my C++ application. The buffer serialized in C++ is deserialized correctly in Python but fails in JavaScript with a metadata byte mismatch error.
Steps to Reproduce:
C++ Code:
arrow::Result<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer>> DataFrame::toBinary(std::vector<std::string> columns,
                                                                  std::optional<std::string> const &index,
                                                                  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> const& metadata) const {
    columns = columns.empty() ? this->columnNames() : columns;

    std::shared_ptr<arrow::RecordBatch> array = m_array;
    if (index) {
        array = array->AddColumn(array->num_columns(), arrow::field(*index, m_index->type()), m_index).MoveValueUnsafe();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<arrow::io::BufferOutputStream> output_stream;
    ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(output_stream, arrow::io::BufferOutputStream::Create());

    // Create IPC writer
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::ipc::RecordBatchWriter> writer;
    ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(writer, arrow::ipc::MakeStreamWriter(output_stream.get(), array->schema()));
    // Write the RecordBatch
    ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(writer->WriteRecordBatch(*array, std::make_shared<arrow::KeyValueMetadata>(metadata)));

    // Finalize the writer
    ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(writer->Close());

    // Retrieve the buffer
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer> buffer;
    ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(buffer, output_stream->Finish());

    return buffer;
}

Python Code:
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.ipc as ipc

buffer = pa.BufferReader(binary_data)
reader = ipc.open_stream(buffer)
table = reader.read_all()
data_frame = table.to_pandas()
print(data_frame.columns)
print(data_frame)

JavaScript Code:

const { tableFromIPC } = require('apache-arrow');

const table = tableFromIPC(binary_data);

Expected Behavior:
The IPC buffer serialized in C++ should be deserialized correctly in both Python and JavaScript.
Actual Behavior:

Python: Deserialization works correctly, and the DataFrame is printed as expected.
Index(['o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v', 'vw', 'n', 'sma<period=30>(c)|sma#00000', 'sma<period=100>(c)|sma#00001', 't'], dtype='object')


JavaScript: Deserialization fails with the following error:
Error fetching market_data data: Error: Expected to read 131072 metadata bytes, but only read 120532.



Error Messages:

JavaScript:
  Error fetching market_data data: Error: Expected to read 131072 metadata bytes, but only read 120532.
  readMetadata message.mjs:99
  next message.mjs:48
  readMessage message.mjs:57
  _readNextMessageAndValidate reader.mjs:321
  next reader.mjs:295
  readAll reader.mjs:156
  tableFromIPC serialization.mjs:29
  transformModelData MarketDataProvider.tsx:38
  fetchData GenericProvider.tsx:35



Environment Details:
C++: Arrow version 14.0.1
Python: Arrow version 5
JavaScript: Arrow version 14.0.1, Node.js 14

Additional Information:

The table schema includes the following columns: ['o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v', 'vw', 'n', 'sma<period=30>(c)|sma#00000', 'sma<period=100>(c)|sma#00001', 't'].

Possible Causes:

There might be an issue with the IPC writer configuration in the C++ code.
There could be a discrepancy in how the Arrow versions handle IPC streams between Python and JavaScript.

Steps Taken to Troubleshoot:

Verified the serialized data in Python to confirm correct deserialization.
Checked the metadata and buffer sizes in both C++ and Python.
Ensured that the same Arrow version is used across C++, Python, and JavaScript environments.

Please help identify the root cause of this issue and suggest a solution.
Component(s)
C++, JavaScript, Python
UPDATE
I DID SOME EXPERIMENT AND I REALIZED IT WAS HOW I WAS PARSING MY msgpack binary to extract the stream. I was using the binary in string format, instead of the Buffer.from(stringBuffer, 'binary')

Does the error still happen if you use the latest versions of the Arrow libraries?
Sometimes this error happens when you try to read a file that's in IPC file format instead of IPC stream format. Are you sure the file you're reading in JavaScript is in IPC stream format?
Can you include some example C++ code that calls the C++ function? Without that I don't think it's really possible to reproduce the error.

so they are currently the same version. 14.0.1. i also confirmed with the pyarrow library that it is indeed a stream. I have posted the code for creating the IPC Stream i use uWS as my server. i created clients for javascript and python to make GET request to receive stream. I can also post the binary in a txt file.

Can you generate a small example IPC stream file that errors like this when read with the JS library? If you can do that, show the full code you're using to generate it, and upload the file somewhere, then we can reproduce and diagnose.

interesting so i did this experiment. saving the raw buffer in a file and reading from both js and python from the file and it works. it seems it may be some issues in transmission or how js is receiving the binary, compared to python.

Ah, that makes more sense. Maybe it's an encoding issue or a character escaping issue? Using a text encoding or escaping special characters can cause Arrow IPC data to get corrupted.

@ianmcook . it seemed  tableFromIPC(Buffer.from(stringBuffer, 'binary')) solved my issue , instead of tableFromIPC(stringBuffer).
